# Linking contributions from a deleted account to a new account

Tags: discussion, support, specific-user, deleted-accounts

I quit this site around $15$ months back. Now I am back and I see that my inbox still has my old "achievements", "comments", etc. Is it possible to link back to my old answers and questions?

Comment: I would imagine that contacting the SE team directly is probably a better venue than asking on meta.

Answer (score 6):

It is most likely *possible* to have your old submissions attached to your new account, however this is an action that can only be done by those with access to the database: SE employees. Your best option is to [contact the SE team](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) directly with your request, explaining the situation as fully as possible.

I know that deleted accounts have been reconstituted in the past, but those that I am aware of were *exceptional* circumstances; much more exceptional that your history.

Be aware that in making this request there is no guarantee that SE will accede to it.